# append value in textarea from selected dropdown without removing previous value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I'm developing web app using `php` I'm facing an issue in appending value from the dropdown to the `textarea`. It displays appended in `html` but not in `textarea`.

If I edit `html` in inspect element then the changes get affected.

**Here is my code:**

JS:

```
$('#txtfieldname').on('change',function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    var fieldName = $(this).val();
    $('#txttext2tpeechmessage').append('{{ '+fieldName+' }}');
});
```

HTML:

```
<select name="txtfieldname" id="txtfieldname" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>                      
</select>
```

Any help will be appreciated..
Thank you in advance..

Comment: try either `$('#txttext2tpeechmessage').val(fieldName)` or `$('#txttext2tpeechmessage').val($('#txttext2tpeechmessage').val() +fieldName)`

Comment: What do you mean by ` display appended in html but not in textarea.`?

Comment: Show more html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

```
$('#txtfieldname').on('change',function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    var fieldName = $(this).val();
    $('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val() +fieldName)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
$('#txtfieldname').on('change',function() {
    var fieldName = $(this).val();
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    $('textarea').val(text.concat(fieldName));});
```